# jquery- stop auto refreshing onClick

Tags: jquery

I'm running a jquery autorefresh code which get active soon the page is loaded. I've set timeinterval to 1second.which means that for every 1 sec page gets refreshed.
I want to know is there any method to stop auto refreshing onclick?

**Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout("dummy()",500); 
});
function dummy(){ 
    setTimeout("checkalerts()",50); 
} 
function checkalerts() { 
    var url="includes/adda/hangouts/display_all_hangouts.php"; 
    $.post(url,function(data){ 
        $("#print").html(data).show(); 
        setTimeout("dummy()",1000); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: There are alot of diff ways to do this, post your auto refresh code and we can give you a snippet that works best with what you currently have. BTW, why are you refreshing every second?

Comment: thank you dear allen. Here's the code snippet i'm using ..
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout("dummy()",500);
});
function dummy(){
setTimeout("checkalerts()",50);
}

function checkalerts()
{
var url="includes/adda/hangouts/display_all_hangouts.php";
$.post(url,function(data){
$("#print").html(data).show();
setTimeout("dummy()",1000);

});
}


</script>

Comment: btw...the data in my database will keep changing so i want to display updated data on a page..hope you get it..

Comment: Dont forget to vote up gAMBOOKa's answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further reviewing your code, I'm a little baffled. I don't understand why you need so many timers. You essentially have one timer that calls dummy() every half a second, and that function creates a new timer (*every half a second, a new timer is created*) every 50 millisecond.

And when posting you're calling dummy again every second. This is some serious WTF code!

---

Anyway, updated code, this snippet should work

```
var timer;

$( document ).ready(function(){ 
    timer = setTimeout( "checkalerts()", 1000);
});

function checkalerts() 
{ 
    var url="includes/adda/hangouts/display_all_hangouts.php"; 

    $.post( url, function( data )
    { 
        $("#print").html(data).show();
    });
}

$( '#my-button' ).click( function()
{
    clearTimeout( timer );
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! I hope you understand *why* this works and your code doesn't. Copy pasting will only get you so far, you know!

Comment: yes i think i do..
thank you for the concern..
see you soon with new questions...:)

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault() after your first click

Comment: How does this remove the interval that is refreshing?

Comment: thank you satish for your kind and quick reply..
i'm new to jquery, i didn't get your last reply ..
what's preventDefault()   ?